# how to get custom environment variables in IConfiguration in .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(a => { 
        a.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

and inside the API I'm calling   like this, and It is not supporting for custom variables, How do I get custom variable 
I already created a custom variable in the system.

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get() {
    var t = configuration.GetSection("yash2").Value;
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave the wrong answer earlier. Thanks, James for pointing out that.

To load environment variables to the application, you need to store variables with __ seperator.

```
yesh2__config1="config1Value"
yesh2__config2="config2Value"
```

Then it will be available here.

```
configuration.GetSection("yash2")
```

Instead of loading all Environment Variables, you can pass which key you wanted to load also.

```
 a.AddEnvironmentVariables("yesh2");
```

Comment: I believe he was asking about bringing in system environmental variables, not using an appsettings.json file.  To bring in a section from environmental variables, the environmental variable would need to be like "`yash2__BaseUrl`" and set to "`value1`". `configuration.GetSection("yash2")` would return a configuration section with all of the environmental variables with the prefix `yash2__`.